# Help with writing the following as a partial fraction $\frac{4x+5}{x^3+1}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help with writing the following as a partial fraction:

$$\frac{4x+5}{x^3+1}$$

My attempts so far are to factor $x^3$ into $(x+1)$ and $(x^2-x+1)$

This gives me: $A(x^2-x+1)+B(x+1)$.

But I have problems with solving the equation system that this gives:

$A = 0$ (since there are no $x^2$ terms in $4x+5$)

$-A+B =4$ (since there are $4$ $x$ terms in $4x+5$)

$A+B = 5$ (since the constant is $5$ in $4x+5$)

this gives me $A=0.5$ and $B=4.5$ and $\frac{1/2}{x+1}, \frac{9/2}{x^2-x+1}$

This is appearantly wrong. Where is my reasoning faulty?

Thank you!

Comment: This type needs three unknown letters. Set it up as $(4x+5)/(x^3+1)=(Ax+B)/(x^2-x+1)+C/(x+1).$ Generally there needs to be a linear term above an irreducible quadratic (or its powers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use one less exponent per factor in the numerator after your factorization.

This leads to:

$$\frac{Ax+B}{x^2-x+1} + \frac{C}{x+1} = \frac{4x+5}{x^3+1}$$

This gives us:

$$Ax^2 + Ax + Bx + B + Cx^2 - Cx + C = 4x + 5$$

This leads to:

$A + C = 0$

$A + B - C = 4$

$B + C = 5$

yielding:

$$A = -\frac{1}{3}, B = \frac{14}{3}, C = \frac{1}{3}$$

Writing the expansion out yields:

$$\frac{4x+5}{x^3+1} = \frac{14 - x}{3(x^2-x+1)} + \frac{1}{3(x+1)}$$

Comment: Great "process" answer and general pointers! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Surprising how many places the partial fraction expansions can be useful! Thx